# Why isn't this jQuery Toggling upon Radio Selection?

Tags: php, jquery

Currently, this is toggling, but it is not toggling the right fields when the individual "Professor" or "Course" Radio buttons are selected. Anyone have some insight why this isnt working?

**Currently its showing all the fields when "Course" radio is selected and when professor is selected they all go away**
[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Thanks!

```
<!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':radio[value="Coursee"]').click(function() {
        $('#courseFields').toggle(':not(:radio[value="Professor"]:checked)');
    });
    $(':radio[value="Professor"]').click(function() {
        $('#ProfFields').toggle(':not(:radio[value="Coursee"]:checked)');
    });
});
</script>
<?php
require_once('inc/dbc1.php');
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=ureviewdu.db.6511651.hostedresource.com;dbname=ureviewdu', $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT name
    FROM Department
    ;');
$sth->execute(array());
?>
<div id="popup_name" class="popup_block">
    <h2 style="padding:0; margin:0;">Add a:</h2><br>
    <form action="inc/add_p_c_validate.php" method="post" id="addition"> 
        Professor<input type="radio" name="addType" value="Professor" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Course<input type="radio" name="addType" value="Coursee" /> 

        <div id="courseFields">
            <br>Course: <input type="text" name="name" style="width:385px;" /><br> 
            Department: <select name="deptName" id="deptName" style="width:350px;">
                                    <?php while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {echo "<option>".$row['name']." "."</option>";} ?></select>   
            Email: <input type="text" name="email"  class="l" />
         </div><!--/courseFields-->
         <div id="ProfFields">
         <br>First Name: <input type="text" name="name" style="width:385px;" /><br>
         <br>Last Name: <input type="text" name="name" style="width:385px;" /><br>
          Department: <select name="deptName" id="deptName" style="width:350px;">
         <?php while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {echo "<option>".$row['name']." "."</option>";} ?></select>   
         </div><!--/ProfFields-->
        <input type="submit" name="submit" /> 
    </form> 
</div><!--popup_name-->
```

Comment: Because you have two radio buttons with the name "addType". Separate them by using :radio[value="Professor"] selector instead of :radio[name="addType"] for first entry, and "Course" for second.

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Comment: I've updated my code to reflect your thoughts and it still isnt differentiating between Course and Professor, one of them works, the other doesnt. Mind showing some code please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use the .toggle( showOrHide ) version of toggle, in which case you should pass a boolean value to show/hide the element hence you need to use .length>0 for $(':not(:radio[value="Professor"]:checked)') or $(':not(:radio[value="Course"]:checked)')

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(':radio[name="addType"]').click(function() {
            $('#courseFields').toggle($(':radio[value="Professor"]:checked').length == 0);
            $('#ProfFields').toggle($(':radio[value="Course"]:checked').length == 0);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Cybernate - this actually kills both options. It shows all the fields like it is not, as soon as you click a radio button - its hides everything.

Comment: @user700070: Updated the post. Can u check it now?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to hide both the container DIVs:

```
 $("#ProfFields,#courseFields").hide();
```

Then do a simplified version of what you already have:

```
 $("input:radio[name='addType']").click(function(){
      var profFields = ($(this).val()=="Professor");
      $("#ProfFields").toggle(profFields); 
      $("#courseFields").toggle(!profFields);
 });
```

Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/WMvtG/